# How to make a CSS3 chart with position:absolute; work in a box that has a display:inline-block;

Tags: html, css

Please, no javascript.

Imagine this if you will. A page that has hundreds of boxes with each box containing a joke, cite, image... (all boxes with a display:inline-block;).

Now I'm trying to place A chart with a few components with position:absolute; and left: in one of the display:inline-block; boxes with no luck. The chart shows at the left side of the page with the next joke box underneath it.

How do I control it?

Cheers, All.

Part 2 (my box code):

```
.boxDarth{
    border-radius:5px;
    border:1px solid #663810;
    box-shadow:-3px 5px 4px #000000;
    margin:6px 3px;
    padding:6px;
    display:inline-block;

    line-height:1.5;
    text-align:left;
    text-decoration:none;
    font-weight:lighter;
    letter-spacing:1.4;
    text-shadow:-1px 1px 1px #37363b;
    word-wrap:break-word;

    vertical-align:top;
    position:relative;
}
```

The chart ccs is quite long. If what I provide here is not enough, and since I've never asked a question here; should I paste it here? upload a file?

```
.pie{
    position:absolute;
    width:100px;
    height:200px;
    overflow:hidden;
    left:150px;
    -moz-transform-origin:left center;
    -o-transform-origin:left center;
    -webkit-transform-origin:left center;
    transform-origin:left center;
}
```

Comment: Can you post some code?

Answer (score 1):

The container should have `position: relative` as a CSS attribute

Answer (score 1):

The chart has to be a child of the inline block box, and the box needs to have `position: relative;` on it.

```css
.inline-box {
  display: inline-block;
  background: violet;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  position: relative;
}

.chart {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  background: cornsilk;
}
```

```html
<div class="inline-box">
  <div class="chart">
    hi, I'm an absolutely positioned chart inside of a relatively positioned inline box
  </div>
</div>
```